# UC Davis ChemWiki is gone

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

I noticed today that the domain **chemwiki.ucdavis.edu** redirects to **chem.libretexts.org**. While most of the content is still available there, quite a few links may have gone rouge on our site.
The switch must have happened sometime in July last year.

- [old design](https://web.archive.org/web/20160707230513/http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/)
- [new design](https://web.archive.org/web/20160714230450/http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/)
- [redirect](https://web.archive.org/web/20160728230356/http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/)

If you find a broken link I suggest you check if there is a version archived at https://archive.org/web/ and fix the content. If you don't know what to do, you can of course flag for moderator attention.

Comment: I am now fairly certain, that it happend around the time [this post](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/2835/4945) was created as a cautionary monument.

Comment: Note that you can find posts with links to the old ChemWiki address using [this search](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Achemwiki.ucdavis.edu). Out of the first 15 results, though, I only found [one](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/19513) with a broken link (and I suspect, based on the [archive results](http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Theoretical_Chemistry/Symmetry/Group_Theory%3A_Theory), that this particular breakage may have happened already in February-March 2016).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ChemWiki was amalgamated into the LibreTexts project, along with a number of other STEM wikis in July last year. It is run by the same group, under direction of Delmar Larsen at UC Davis.

A snapshot of the LibreText facebook page (urgh... evil) from July 2016

[image]